# Создание расширений VS, сортировка using по длине строки

Tags: visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-extensions

Товарищи, проблема следующая: привык в своих проектах сортировать `using`и (и не только) по длине строки. То есть код рода:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.IO;
```

Я обязательно переделаю в:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
```

И только тогда успокоюсь) 
Так вот. Я немного устал делать это вручную, так что хочу спросить: есть ли какое-либо **легкое** расширение (подозреваю, что `ReSharper` так умеет, но его я не рассматриваю) для `Visual Studio 2017`, способное выполнять сортировку выделенных строк по их длине?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Собственно, никто мне так и не ответил, сам же я не нашел подходящего расширения. Но кто ж мне мешал написать свое? Сие я и сделал. Расширение теперь висит в [Marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/), а именно - [здесь](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=KirAntipov.LineSorterByKir).
 Оформлять сильно все это я, понятное дело, не стал, ибо делал сие только под себя, но мало ли кому-то когда-нибудь тоже пригодится такая мелочь, а ставить внушительные расширения хотят далеко не все.
Ну и давайте заодно уж рассмотрим пример создания такого простейшего *расширения* на поставленной задаче.

---

0) Для начала создадим VSIX Project (расширения для Visual Studio можно писать на Visual C++, Visual Basic, C#. Я это дело писал на C#). Если шаблон такого проекта отсутствует в списке доступных, установите соответствующий пункт с помощью Visual Studio Installer.

1) Добавим в проект элемент `Custom Command` и назовем его "**CommandSort**".
В появившийся класс "**CommandSort.cs**" добавим следующий код:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell;
using System.ComponentModel.Design;

namespace LineSorter
{
    internal sealed class CommandSort
    {
        #region Var
        private AsyncPackage Package { get; }
        public int CommandId { get; } = 0x0100;
        public static CommandSort Instance { get; private set; }
        public static Guid CommandSet { get; } = new Guid("e9f69e2b-6313-4c2b-9765-1ddd6439d519");
        #endregion

        #region Init
        private CommandSort(AsyncPackage Package, OleMenuCommandService CommandService)
        {
            this.Package = Package ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(Package));
            CommandService = CommandService ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(CommandService));
            CommandID menuCommandID = new CommandID(CommandSet, CommandId);
            MenuCommand menuItem = new MenuCommand(Execute, menuCommandID);
            CommandService.AddCommand(menuItem);
        }
        public static async System.Threading.Tasks.Task InitializeAsync(AsyncPackage Package)
        {
            ThreadHelper.ThrowIfNotOnUIThread();
            Instance = new CommandSort(Package, await Package.GetServiceAsync((typeof(IMenuCommandService))) as OleMenuCommandService);
        }
        #endregion

        #region Functions
        private void Execute(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ThreadHelper.ThrowIfNotOnUIThread();
            TextSelection.GetSelection(Package).OrderBy(x => x.Length).ThenBy(x => x).ReplaceSelection();
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

Инициализатор нашей команды, ее ID и GUID в рамках проекта будут установлены VS автоматически. По сути от нас требуется изменить лишь метод `Execute`.
2) Для более удобной работы с выделенным текстом создадим класс "**TextSelection**" и в "**TextSelection.cs**" внесем таковой код:

```
using EnvDTE;
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextManager.Interop;

namespace LineSorter
{
    public static class TextSelection
    {
        #region Var
        public static IServiceProvider ServiceProvider { get; set; }
        #endregion

        #region Functions
        /// <summary>
        /// Получим выделенный текст и избавим его от пробелов и табуляции в начале/конце строк
        /// </summary>
        public static IEnumerable<string> GetSelection(IServiceProvider ServiceProvider)
        {
            TextSelection.ServiceProvider = ServiceProvider;
            IVsTextManager2 textManager = ServiceProvider.GetService(typeof(SVsTextManager)) as IVsTextManager2;
            int result = textManager.GetActiveView2(1, null, (uint)_VIEWFRAMETYPE.vftCodeWindow, out IVsTextView view);
            view.GetSelectedText(out string selectedText);
            return selectedText.Split(new char[] { '\r', '\n' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Select(x => x.Trim(new char[] { ' ', '\t' }));
        }

        public static void ReplaceSelection(this IEnumerable<string> Selections)
        {
            ReplaceSelection(Selections, ServiceProvider);
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Заменим выделенный текст на указанную коллекцию строк
        /// </summary>
        public static void ReplaceSelection(this IEnumerable<string> Selections, IServiceProvider ServiceProvider)
        {
            DTE dte = ServiceProvider?.GetService(typeof(DTE)) as DTE;
            if (dte is null) return;
            IDataObject obj = Clipboard.GetDataObject();
            Clipboard.SetText(string.Join("\r\n", Selections));
            dte.ExecuteCommand("Edit.Paste");
            Clipboard.SetDataObject(obj);
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

Логика кода, думаю, вполне ясна. Однако заострю внимание на методе замены выделенного текста на новую коллекцию (`ReplaceSelection`). Изначально код выглядел так:

```
DTE dte = ServiceProvider?.GetService(typeof(DTE)) as DTE;
if (dte is null) return;
EnvDTE.TextSelection selection = dte.ActiveDocument?.Selection as EnvDTE.TextSelection;
if (selection is null) return;
selection.Text = string.Join("\r\n", Selections);
```

И все кажется вполне логичным: просто заменяем выделенный текст на новый. Во многих мануалах я как раз такой подход и видел. Однако предостерегаю от такого подхода к работе с выделенным текстом, так как работает это жутко медленно. Свойство `EnvDTE.TextSelection.Text` при установке зачем-то парсит весь вставляемый текст, разбивая его на смысловые единицы. Поясню: к примеру, мы имеем 2 таких `using`'a, которые мы хотим отсортировать:

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop;
using Task = System.Threading.Tasks.Task;
```

Для нашего алгоритма важно лишь то, что это **2** строки. Однако указанное свойство разбивает все это дело на смысловой набор:

```
using, Microsoft, VisualStudio, Shell, Interop, using, Task, System, Threading, Tasks, Task
```

И мы имеем уже не **2** строки, а **11** отдельно обрабатываемых элементов. С ростом числа сортируемых строк число обрабатываемых смысловых единиц катастрофически растет, так что простенькое действие при таком подходе начинает занимать внушительный промежуток времени.
 Именно поэтому я воспользовался маленькой хитростью:

1. Я сохраняю текущее состояние буфера обмена
2. После этого загоняю в него объединенную коллекцию наших строк
3. А теперь уже запускаю функцию вставки из самой VS (как бы <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +
   <kbd>V</kbd>). Так что текст моментально вставляется на место выделенного,
   после чего форматируется самой средой
4. После сего действа возвращаю буферу обмена прошлое состояние

Честно - не знаю, насколько хорошо это решение, однако оно уж точно быстрее стандартного пути. Если будут идеи более правильной реализации - буду рад выслушать!

3) Что ж. Разобрались, собственно, с кодом. Осталось навести порядок в конфиге (`CommandSortPackage.vsct`):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CommandTable xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2005-10-18/CommandTable" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Extern href="stdidcmd.h" />
  <Extern href="vsshlids.h" />
  <Commands package="guidCommandSortPackage">
    <Groups>
      <Group guid="guidCommandSortPackageCmdSet" id="MyMenuGroup" priority="0x0600">
        <!-- IDM_VS_CTXT_CODEWIN - контекстное меню VS -->
        <Parent guid="guidSHLMainMenu" id="IDM_VS_CTXT_CODEWIN" />
      </Group>
    </Groups>
    <Buttons>
      <Button guid="guidCommandSortPackageCmdSet" id="CommandSortId" priority="0x0100" type="Button">
        <Parent guid="guidCommandSortPackageCmdSet" id="MyMenuGroup" />
        <Icon guid="guidImages" id="bmpPicArrows" />
        <Strings>
          <ButtonText>Сортировать линии</ButtonText>
        </Strings>
      </Button>
    </Buttons>
    <Bitmaps>
      <Bitmap guid="guidImages" href="Resources\CommandSort.png" usedList="bmpPic1, bmpPic2, bmpPicSearch, bmpPicX, bmpPicArrows, bmpPicStrikethrough" />
    </Bitmaps>
  </Commands>

  <!-- Устанавливаем shortcut для нашей команды -->
  <KeyBindings>
    <KeyBinding guid="guidCommandSortPackageCmdSet" id="CommandSortId" editor="guidVSStd97" mod1="Control" mod2="Control" key1="E" key2="L" />
  </KeyBindings>

  <Symbols>
    <GuidSymbol name="guidCommandSortPackage" value="{7fb18e2a-1a51-4dbb-b676-a3514e44823d}" />
    <GuidSymbol name="guidCommandSortPackageCmdSet" value="{e9f69e2b-6313-4c2b-9765-1ddd6439d519}">
      <IDSymbol name="MyMenuGroup" value="0x1020" />
      <!-- Обратите внимание, что value равно значению, которое указано у нас в CommandSort.cs! -->
      <IDSymbol name="CommandSortId" value="0x0100" />
    </GuidSymbol>
    <GuidSymbol name="guidImages" value="{f2b4c3e0-a959-40c0-be9d-315e5ca1615c}">
      <IDSymbol name="bmpPic1" value="1" />
      <IDSymbol name="bmpPic2" value="2" />
      <IDSymbol name="bmpPicSearch" value="3" />
      <IDSymbol name="bmpPicX" value="4" />
      <IDSymbol name="bmpPicArrows" value="5" />
      <IDSymbol name="bmpPicStrikethrough" value="6" />
    </GuidSymbol>
  </Symbols>
</CommandTable>
```

Таким образом мы добавляем кнопку с указанным текстом и ссылающуюся на наше действие в *контекстное меню* VS, а также связываем с ним *горячие клавиши*:
 (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd>) + (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>)
4) Вот и все, наше простенькое расширение готово. Вы можете отдебажить его с помощью экспериментальной версии VS, или же просто собрать его, после чего среди уймы пакетов Вы найдете заветный файлик с расширением *.vsix, при помощи которого Вы можете либо сразу установить расширение в свою студию, либо же даже опубликовать его)

---

А на сием - все) Спасибо за внимание)